# Permutation and combination,Set problem,

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,\dots,98,99,100\}$
In how many ways can 5 numbers a,b,c,d,e be selected such that:

$$a\geq b\geq c\geq d\geq e$$

Answer is $104 \choose 99$ or $\frac{104!}{99!5!}$

I need the explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: the numbers selected can be repeated or not?

Comment: they can be repeated.

Comment: I have answered your question, it is quiet simple, just read it carefully, I am glad you are inquisitive in finding "why" this answer is true. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is same as saying, select 5 objects from 100 distinct  objects with repetitions,

which is same as arranging $5 "*"$ marks and $99 "|"$ (bars). (because 99 bars will make 100 compartments.)

One combination will be like this

$|||||||||||||||||...(99 bars)||||||||||||*****$

which represents 1 has been selected 5 times (because 5 x marks are in first position)

another combination will be of type

$|||||||||||||||||...|||||||||*|*|**|*$

Which represents $1, 2,2,3,4$ have been choosen (see the position of $"*"$ marks)

so total number of combinations = arrangement of $99 bars$ and  $5 "*"$ (total 104 objects, 99 alike of one type, 5 alike of other type)

$$= \frac{104!}{99! 5!}$$

or they are just 5-combinations from 100 objects = $\binom{100+5-1}{5}$

$$=\binom{104}{5}  =\binom{104}{99} $$ (property of binomical coefficients)

Comment: I know how selecting n objects from m distinct objects works. But I am slightly confused with your explanation. (1) |||||||||||||||||...(99bars)||||||||||||∗∗∗∗∗--- which represents 1 has been selected 5 times (because 5 x marks are in first position). It seems to me that the “*” are placed after the bars and hence are placed at the last 5 positions. (2) It is difficult to relate |||||||||||||||||...|||||||||∗|∗|∗∗|∗---Which represents 1, 2, 2, 3, 4…(see the position of "∗" marks)

Comment: I assume that rightmost position is the first (like the right most digit in a number is ones place), you can assume from left, as you wish. (just to explain i did this)

Comment: Explanation makes it clearer except that your convention is not that common.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Every $a,b,c,d,e$ from $A$ determine exactly one multiset of $A$.

Comment: Help me a bit more please :)

Comment: I am 100% certain you covered multisets in your class. Check your notes. This site is not here to solve your homework but to help you with it.

Comment: No we havent covered multisets :(

Comment: Then you called them combinations with repetition. Same thing.

Comment: I am still unable to get you.

Comment: Okay, what is your background then? The thing is that your question on dice and this one cover the theory behind combinations with repetition (or multisets). I presume, therefore, you did some work in class on something like this? For example, you first learned permutations, then combinations and so on?

Comment: You basically asked $3$ questions, all can be answered the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Well,we choose five objects it's automatically sorted.so,first take out 5 objects we get, 100C5,Now if we have repeatitions ,we get
For 1 no is repeated and 4 objects taken out 100C4*4 similarly for others we get 100C3*6,100C2*4 and 100C1*4 now ,if we add we get 100C1+100C2*4+100C3*6+100C4*4+100C5
Now, looking at the expansion of
(1+x)^100 and (1+x)^4
(1+x)^100= 1+100C1*x..........
(1+x)^4=1+4C1*x+4C2*x^2..............
Multiplying both and eq the coefficients of x^5,
So,we get,
104C5=104!/5!99!